# ClickOnce publish for multiple environments (TFS Build)

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, tfsbuild

I have a clickonce application that I am trying to get published to multiple directories (one fore each environment) during the same build. Im having trouble figuring out the timing of every thing.

So far I have:

```
<Target Name="PublishForEachEnv">
    <Message Text="TEST PublishForEachEnv" />
    <Message Text="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" />
    <Message Text="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />

    <MSBuild Projects ="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
             Properties ="PublishDir=$(PublishDir)\dev;"
             Targets="Publish" />

    <MSBuild Projects ="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
             Properties ="PublishDir=$(PublishDir)\qa;"
             Targets="Publish" />
</Target>
```

I call this target from the csproj file:

```
<Target Name="ClientPublish"
      AfterTargets="Build">

     <CallTarget Targets="PublishForEachEnv" />
</Target>
```

I have tried multiple varations of this but the most current error I get is:
 There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "PublishForEachEnv".

On the line: 
    Targets="Publish" />

The only other way I can think to do this would be to create a csproj file for each environment. I was hoping there was a better way.